assert that all elements of a list are called on 4 different functions using assertAll
I would like to write a test in which I pass in as an argument a list of values, and I assert that 4 different methods are called using each value. For example
@ParameterizedTest
@SomeKindOfSource
public void runTest(List<Integer> ints){
  for (int i : ints){
    assertAll(
      () -> verify(myMock, times(1)).method1(eq(i)),
      () -> verify(myMock, times(1)).method2(eq(i)),
      () -> verify(myMock, times(1)).method3(eq(i)),
      () -> verify(myMock, times(1)).method4(eq(i))
    );
  }
}

This asserts that, for each element, all 4 methods are called once.  However, if the first element fails, the test short-circuits and the remainder are not called.
How can I pass a single list of executables into the assertAll method, such that the test verifies all for assertions for all 4 values before failing if there are any failures?

The whole idea of JUnit is that a test method either passes or fails, and that the failure shows you only the first failed assertion.  If you need to see separate results for each assertion, then you should really set them up as four separate test methods.

What result you want to achieve? Fail only of all verify fails?

This question is similar to: JUnit5 assertAll. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
